# Save output of disp to file

Tags: matlab

I have a line in my program that displays the contents of an object to the console

```
disp(obj);
```

I don't really need the complexity of a database for now. Then, is there a similar function call (or overloading of either obj or disp) that will output (append) the contents of obj to a text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `diary` to save text from your console to a file. More information [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diary.html).

Comment: In conjuction with diary on|off that works great. Thanks.